# Не могу понять код: Перемещение компонента

Tags: c#, unity3d

Знаю, что выставлять целых кусок кода и просить его разобрать не правильно, но как не ищу не могу понять, как он работает, прошел базы по учебнику C#, частично понял, что как, но C# для Unity сильно отличается...

```
public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    private CharacterController _charController;

    void Start() {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update() {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
        movement.y = gravity;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        _charController.Move(movement);
    }
```

Comment: Что такое Vector3 вам понятно?

Comment: Да, это вектор в 3х мерном пространстве, который определяется по 3 координатам. Ну и  Vector3 поворачивает по направлению вектора.

Comment: Уже неплохо. Что делает метод ClampMagnitude знаете? Смотрели [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html)?

Comment: Как я понял, просто обрезает вектор, чтобы он не был больше maxLength, но вот зачем не понимаю. Может он просто ограничивает скорость перемещения? Но как максимальную длину можно брать скорость? И то и то float, но они же отвечают за разные параметры.

Comment: Input.GetAxis() возвращает число от -1 до 1. А нам нужно, чтобы объект двигался с определенной скоростью speed. Вот мы и удлиняем вектор до длины speed, а потом передвигаем объект на этот вектор. Так как длина вектора равна speed, то и переместим наш объект мы на расстояние speed. Как-то так

Comment: Но speed это же коэффициент для ускорения передвижения путем удлинения вектора перемещения... Так почему он (speed) равен длине вектора?

Comment: Не speed равен длине вектора,  а длина вектора устанавливается равной speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0f; // Скорость передвижения
    public float gravity = -9.8f; // Гравитация (по оси y)
    private CharacterController _charController; // Ссылка на контроллер игрока

    void Start() {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>(); // Получаем ссылку на скрипт контроллера игрока
    }

    void Update() {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed; // *: получаем перемещение по оси X
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed; // **: получаем перемещение по оси Z
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ); // Создаем вектор перемещения по осям X и Z, а по Y устанавливаем 0
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed); // Устанавливаем длину вектора равную скорости speed (чтобы потом скорость была именно ровно speed)
        movement.y = gravity; // Устанавливаем y равным гравитации, чтобы помимо перемещения она учитывалась
        movement *= Time.deltaTime; // 3: Домножаем на Time.deltaTime, чтобы скорость передвижения не зависела от ФПС
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement); // Переводим имеющийся вектор в мировые координаты
        _charController.Move(movement); // Вызываем функцию перемещения в контроллере
    }
```

`*`: Возвращает `-1` при зажатии `A`, `1` при зажатии `D`
`**`: Возвращает `-1` при зажатии `S`, `1` при зажатии `W`

---

Ответ на вопрос из комментария:

> Зачем устанавливать длину вектора перемещения равной speed

Допустим, что нажаты кнопки W и D. Тогда вы будете иметь вектор перемещения (1, 0, 1). Вам нужно, чтобы объект перемещался со скорость `speed`. Пусть `speed=5`. 
Вы **НЕ** можете просто домножить вектор на скорость, так как тогда получите вектор (5,0,5). Если вы переместите персонажа на этот вектор, то на какое расстояние он переместится? По тереме Пифагора на расстояние `sqrt(5^2 + 5^2) = sqrt(50) ≈ 7`. 
НО скорость объекта равна 5, он не может переместиться на расстояние 7!
Поэтому мы не домножаем вектор на скаляр, а устанавливаем длину вектора равной 5. 
Тогда вектор станет примерно равен (3.5355, 0, 3.5355). И его длина будет равна 5 => скорость, как и должно, равна 5, ведь мы перемещаем объект на вектор.\

Comment: Вроде бы всё понял, большое спасибо!